# Debugging "Application.exe has stopped working" with .NET

Tags: .net, windows, debugging

On a customer's computer, my application immediately crashes with the message "Application.exe has stopped working".

I'm using .NET Framework 2.0.

I'm using a catch-all exception handler in the Main method.
The main method doesn't use any of the project assemblies. Therefore, if it was a missing assembly, this exception handler should get called.

I do not have access to the client computer. How can I debug this problem?

Comment: is the proper framework installed on the target computer ?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct, the JIT compiler can inline methods.

Comment: Yes, the framework is installed. Hans, good thought. I just checked this by removing the most important DLL, and my program catches it just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your application in Debug mode, give it to the client, hopefully next time it happens the JIT debugger will kick off and give you a stack-trace.

You could also look at increase your logging verbosity. Using something like Nlog and some logging goes far to detecting issues. Have a peek at the [nlog tutorial](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Tutorial). Logging is something which is massively underused in most development tasks today :(

Comment: He can check also the OS event viewer

Comment: @sunrisas thats true, but not all logs go there :( its a great resource but active logging is massivly helpful in a situation like this.