# Can't get application to work on another computer after publishing

Tags: c#, deployment, publishing

Hy, I am trying to publish my first application. In the debugging mode everything works fine, on my computer it also works without a problem, but on the other computer I can't get it to work. When I try to run it I get the message ""application" has stopped working" . When I click on view problem details I get this:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   robnoknjigovodstvo.exe
Problem Signature 02:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   51cac5f7
Problem Signature 04:   System.Data
Problem Signature 05:   4.0.30319.17929
Problem Signature 06:   4ffa5def
Problem Signature 07:   1de2
Problem Signature 08:   5f
Problem Signature 09:   System.InvalidOperationException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1050
Additional Information 1:   aa76
Additional Information 2:   aa76315143599a541a5fa1df4fbde453
Additional Information 3:   0709
Additional Information 4:   0709e632ea855b8ded4d7d20096b20d8
```

On the computer I developed the application I have 32 bit windows, and on the other one is 64bit version and I tried to change platform target but it didn't help

Comment: Impossible to answer, is it access rights? file paths?

Comment: Probably a doh moment. Can you deploy to another machine with a 32 bit OS successfully.

Comment: Yes, difficult to say.  Hazarding a guess:  `System.Data` paired with `System.InvalidOperationException` suggested you got an error trying access a database/datasource.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Can't try that at the moment unfortunately

Comment: @DonBoitnott maybe with the database, because I have it in the program, but as I am new to this don't really know what is the problem

Comment: thanks everyone for trying to help and comments. the problem was in this "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" and .accdb database, because on the other computer there is office 2003 so I needed .mdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Debugging "Application.exe has stopped working" with .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347394/debugging-application-exe-has-stopped-working-with-net).
Check if you have permissions to write or read if you are accessing the file system.
Also, make sure the other system has the adequate .NET framework installed.
Change the target to Any CPU.
Also, a good idea would be to wrap your code in a try-catch block and write the error to disk (on a location for which you have write permissions).

Answer (score -1):

maybe , you did not included all dll in your project

Comment: That would be a different exception.